# Как c помощью argparse в зависимости от значения основного ключа парсить остальные ключи?

Tags: python, argparse

Всем Здравствуйте!

Есть основной ключ: **target** принимающий значение ***a, b, c***.
В зависимости от значения **target** есть свой набор обязательных (**mandatory**) и опциональных (**opc**) ключей. Есть ключи которые могут быть для всех **target** (*for_all_target_n*). Но могут не пересекаться.

Например: ( "_n" - n номер параметра)

**target = a**:
*a_mandatory_1, a_mandatory_2, for_all_target_1, a_opc_1*

**target = b:**
*b_mandatory_1, b_opc_1, b_opc_2, for_all_target_1*

**target = c:**
*c_mandatory_1, c_opc_1, c_opc_2*

Как корректно описать парсер на ***argparse***?
При этом хотелось бы иметь возможность "красиво" расширять список, не загромождать код.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обернуть это все в словарь и работать через него

Comment: Проще всего в этом случае разделить обработку аргументов на два уровня. Сначала, получаем `target`, потом на его основе конструируем или выбираем из готовых парсер для конкретной цели. Обратите внимание на [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).